# webpack jplayer: Cannot set property jplayer of undefined

Tags: webpack, jplayer

While bundling js files using `webpack`, the library `jplayer` also gets bundled in the `bundle.js` file. But when the webpage loads on browser, it shows an error on console that `cannot set property jplayer of undefined`. I am confused about the error that is it due to webpack or is there a bug in jplayer library. 
Help is super ultra highly appreciated.

`jplayer.js`

```
(function (root, factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory); // jQuery Switch
    // define(['zepto'], factory); // Zepto Switch
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery')); // jQuery Switch
    //factory(require('zepto')); // Zepto Switch
} else {
    // Browser globals
    if(root.jQuery) { // Use jQuery if available
        factory(root.jQuery);
    } else { // Otherwise, use Zepto
        factory(root.Zepto);
    }
}
}(this, function ($, undefined) {

// Adapted from jquery.ui.widget.js (1.8.7): $.widget.bridge - Tweaked $.data(this,XYZ) to $(this).data(XYZ) for Zepto
$.fn.jPlayer = function( options ) {    //cannot set property jplayer error is mapped here
    var name = "jPlayer";
    var isMethodCall = typeof options === "string",
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
        returnValue = this;

    // allow multiple hashes to be passed on init
    options = !isMethodCall && args.length ?
        $.extend.apply( null, [ true, options ].concat(args) ) :
        options;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meent the same situation today, after I rewrited my webpack config. As lazy as me, I use the same webpack.config.json in both webpack-dev-server and webpack.

The problem on me happend on when I split my project like this:

```
// output for js
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname + '/build'),
    filename: './res/js/[name]_[hash:10].js'
},

//output for html
var pages = getEntry(['./home/en/*.html','./home/cn/*.html'],'home/');
for (var chunkname in pages) {
    var conf = {
        filename: path.join(path.dirname(pages[chunkname]).replace('home/','build/'),path.basename(pages[chunkname])),
        template: pages[chunkname],
        favicon: './img/favicon.ico',
        inject: true,
        hash: true,
        minify: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
        },
        chunks: ['vendor','css/[name].css', chunkname]
    };
    plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin(conf));
```

Then all JS went wrong, console told me with the same error. I checked the function of **_webpack_require_** , and found all the map number is wrong with what it should be.

Then I checked webpack_dev_server's log, and found this:

```
               ..\build\en\aboutus-company.html    11.3 kB          [emitted]  
              ..\build\en\aboutus-news.html    6.26 kB          [emitted]  
           ..\build\en\aboutus-privacy.html    8.58 kB          [emitted]  
           ..\build\en\aboutus-service.html    10.7 kB          [emitted]  
                     ..\build\en\index.html    10.9 kB          [emitted]  
              ..\build\en\monetization.html    6.63 kB          [emitted]  
             ..\build\en\news-161017-1.html    7.76 kB          [emitted]  
             ..\build\en\news-161017-2.html    8.71 kB          [emitted]  
             ..\build\en\news-161017-3.html     9.9 kB          [emitted]  
                     ..\build\en\owner.html     5.9 kB          [emitted]  
                       ..\build\en\sdk.html    5.29 kB          [emitted]  
            ..\build\en\successstories.html    7.72 kB          [emitted]  
           ..\build\cn\aboutus-company.html    11.3 kB          [emitted]  
              ..\build\cn\aboutus-news.html    6.26 kB          [emitted]  
           ..\build\cn\aboutus-privacy.html    8.58 kB          [emitted]  
           ..\build\cn\aboutus-service.html    10.7 kB          [emitted]  
                     ..\build\cn\index.html    10.9 kB          [emitted]  
              ..\build\cn\monetization.html    6.63 kB          [emitted]  
             ..\build\cn\news-161017-1.html    7.76 kB          [emitted]  
             ..\build\cn\news-161017-2.html    8.71 kB          [emitted]  
             ..\build\cn\news-161017-3.html     9.9 kB          [emitted]  
                     ..\build\cn\owner.html     5.9 kB          [emitted]  
                       ..\build\cn\sdk.html    5.29 kB          [emitted]  
            ..\build\cn\successstories.html    7.72 kB          [emitted]
```

It emitted files into the sub-folder. When I try this path, all things went ok.